# Android populating RecyclerView while parser is still working

Tags: android, parsing, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

In my app, I use to populate my recyclerview with items result of parsing XML api in asyncTask, the actual logic is that items are displayed in the onPostExecute event, but for some reason (Large amount of data, network speed or quality, the parsing time can exceed 1min, and then users suppose that was an ANR or a bug even if the loading animation is still showing and generates a large bounce rate for my app, so the question is there a technic to pupulate the recycler while the parser is still working in background, I think that update and publishprogress methods of asyncTask don't do the trick.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Where is code? Without it we can't help you !!

Comment: if you are loading data, then you must be using a loop. Inside the loop, check the size of list/adapter/map you are using to populate the RecyclerView, if it has changed then populate the view. A simple IF condition can do the trick for you

Comment: If you have a really large amount of data, maybe you should divide it into chunks if you are able to interfere their generation?

Comment: @GeetChoubey the adapter is created in postexecute and UI can't be updated in doInBackground

Comment: @piotr.wittchen no I can't the feed does not support paging otherwise a continuous scroll can hardly help

Comment: Handler can be used to make UI changes